# Converting from BTEQ on mainframe to Teradata procedure

Tags: teradata, procedure

We have a bunch of JCL on our mainframe including references to BTEQ scripts and I'm wondering if it would make more sense to import the code in the scripts stored on the mainfraime to new procedures on Teradata.  The existing BTEQ scripts would change to simply call the new procedure on Tdata.

With the one example I've seen, there are differences are in the way the comments are noted.  BTEQ uses asterisks and SQLA procedures uses double-dashes.

I'm thinking if the contents of the scripts were converted to procedures using an automated process, Tdata could compile the script and not have to parse the SQL from the mainframe so executing the code would be easier to execute on the Tdata server.

Are there discussions on this kind of conversion I'm not finding?

I did find [this](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Query_Management_Tools/B035-2414-086K/ScriptsRunFilesMacrosandStoredProcedures_USE_2414.html) and [this](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Stored-Procedure-Vs-Bteq/td-p/52340)

Thanks for your help.

---

To be clear, I'm not referring to BTEQ scripts with TPT/load functions, only scripts moving data from one Tdata table to another while performing transformations or joins.

The sample script I have takes over 4 hours to run from the mainframe, but the explain statement said it should run in 30 minutes, plus recommended collecting statistics.  When I tried to run it with my credentials it ran out of spool space on step 11 of 13 after running 20 minutes or so, so basically on the last step.

I'm getting the impression that Tdata has no optimizations for persistent procedures or macros like SQL Server and Oracle, although I'm surprised by that.  I would expect code run in a persistent object on the server would perform better than code passed through an external source, but I'm not an expert on Tdata's optimizations on their procedures.  Maybe as the commenters say they don't have any.

Comment: performance difference between parsing the sql and running procedures is negligible from experience. It may have been the case a long time ago, but with modern hardware, I doubt there is much merit in such conversion

Comment: Stored procedures are great if they solve a problem you cannot accomplish with regular SQL, a BTEQ script, or you have a transactional active data warehouse environment. Taking a batch process from the mainframe and porting it to SPL will not likely yield a substantial improvement in performance. Your JCL and COBOL programmers might be able to retire sooner though.